# What conditions can we implement for a function to determine it to be one-one using differentiation?

Tags: functions, derivatives

My teacher told me that for a function to be one-one it's derivative needs to be greater than or equal to zero or less than or equal to zero. While it's true for the greater than or less than part I have some confusion regarding the equal to zero condition.

It's true for the function $x^3$, but it can never be true for $x^2$ or $x^4$.  If anyone can help me out it'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The derivative for $x^3$ is zero at zero too but it's an injective function.

Comment: What your teacher told you is not true.  For instance, the injective function $f: \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = 1/x$ has a negative derivative when $x < 0$ and a positive derivative when $x > 0$.  It seems to me that you need the domain to be $\mathbb{R}$, so that the injective function is [monotonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).

Comment: Had doubts about it too. Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score -1):

The function is on one if for every different x in domain  you get different y from codomain.  Even in $x^2$ or $ x^4$ the points at x=0 .
Let's consider y= $x^2$ for all $x\le 0$ function is decreasing and one one including point x=0. Also for $x\ge 0 $ function is increasing including point x=0. But for all $x\in R $ the function is many one.

Comment: So you're saying that we should divide it into parts according to their derivative and define their domain of definition accordingly?

Comment: This answer doesn't even talk about derivatives.

Comment: I am only talking about defining for any function derivative is only took to justify thoughts. There are many one one functions which are non differentiable. I think to explain the things from definition is better way . If still you feel I should differentiate and justify then I do not have same thoughts that one should develop concepts from tools instead of using tools to justify the cocept.